# Using non-ASCII character as JavaScript object key

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object:

```
var obj = {
  'ア' : 'testing',
  'ダ' : '2015-5-15',
  'ル' : 123,
  'ト' : 'Good'
};
```

How do I access the values by its non-ASCII key (it's a Japanese character in this case)?

Can't use `obj.ア` or `obj.'ア'` for sure, which will give JavaScript parse error.

Comment: Is this JavaScript? That is not a proper JavaScript object: it's using `=>` instead of `:`

Comment: `obj.ア` works for me in the Chrome developer console..

Comment: @jasonscript sorry, that's a typo, now corrected.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm using CasperJS. It said Parse Error ...

Comment: You can only use dot notation if the property name is a valid variable name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a subscript to reference the object:

```
> var obj = {
  'ア' : 'testing',
  'ダ' : '2015-5-15',
  'ル' : 123,
  'ト' : 'Good'
};
> undefined
> obj['ア']
> "testing"
```

You should also not that object keys and values in JavaScript objects are separated by `:`(colons) not `=>` (fat commas)

Answer (score 5):

You can use property accessors:

`obj['ト']`

Example:

```
var obj = {
  'ア': 'testing',
  'ダ': '2015-5-15',
  'ル': 123,
  'ト': 'Good'
};

console.log(obj['ト']);
> Good
```

MDN: [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score -2):

How about this one:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script language=javascript>
        var obj = {
'ア':'testing',
'ダ':'2015-5-15',
'ル':123,
'ト':'Good'
};
alert(obj.ア);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but this results in parse error in Casper JS.

Comment: language attribute is deprecated for years. And CasperJS syntax is slightly different than normal JS.